# Why Can't You Put <body> content in the <head> element?

Tags: html

My friend has tried to code a website like this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <h1>
        My Website
      </h1>
    </div>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <a>example link</a>
    </nav>
</body>
```

he hasn't used <!DOCTYPE html> and he has also put his page header in the <head> element. when I try to tell him that you need a <!DOCTYPE html> and you cant put content in the <head> element he says well it worked and you still haven't told me what's wrong with doing that. I don't know to explain it to him so can someone please say why you can't do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure your friend proposes violates [**the global structure of an HTML document**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html); the `<body>` tag must contain the document's actual **content**, whereas the `<head>` tag must only contain information **describing** the document.

- The
  [**`<body>` tag**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) permits any **[flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/content-models.html#flow-content-0)** within it (such
  as `<div>`):

  [image: body permitted]
- Whereas the [**`<head>` tag**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) is reserved for **[metadata content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/content-models.html#metadata-content-0)**
  (such as `<meta>`):

  [image: head permitted]
- And the [**`<div>` element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) must reside within a parent that accepts flow content:

  [image]

The incorrect markup will in fact render correctly on the page, because most browsers are actually intelligent enough to know that the markup is incorrect, and *correct* it themselves. If you inspect the DOM, you'll find that it has automatically been updated to correctly shift the `<div>` element (and its content) to **within** the `<body>` element (just *before* `<nav>`):

[image: Fixed]

Answer (score 0):

< !DOCTYPE html > was introduced in HTML5. I believe earlier versions of the HTML standard also did not specify a lot of these elements hence most browsers will still render pages without them in order to maintain backwards compatibility.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode.